# Silverlight DataForm+ChildWindows+MVVM: ComboBox's DataField dont get populated

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-5.0

i have my View Page with a GridView control. Items in the Grid are edited using a popup Childwindows with the following xaml:

```
        <toolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>

                    <toolkit:DataField Label="Avisar a: ">
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sucursales}"/>
                    </toolkit:DataField>

                    <toolkit:DataField Label="Mensaje:">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding mensaje, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </toolkit:DataField>

                    <toolkit:DataField Label="Estado: ">
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EstadosMensaje}"/>
                    </toolkit:DataField>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>

    </toolkit:DataForm>
```

DataContext to this popup is injected view constructor from the parent view as follow:

```
AlertaForm frm = new AlertaForm(DataContext as AlertasViewModel);
frm.Show();

//ChildWindows constructor
public AlertaForm(AlertasViewModel viewModel){
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

As you can see, ChildWindows and parent view share the same ViewModel.
The problem is that ComboBox controls dont get populated. TextBox field are binded correctly,they display values from DataContext property, that is confusing because that prove that the DataForm recognize the ViewModel passed to the ChildWindows AlertaForm.
Obviously i'm missing something here but cannot figure out what is.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I end up throwing away the User control with the DataForm together
>   sticking in ChildWindows with common controls. It seems that DataForm is not sweet to 
>   complex scenarios